# Circuit is oscillating - why?

Tags: debugging, oscillation

One area of a circuit I'm looking at is the schematic shown below.

The Vin is a discrete signal, currently, I'm not sure of what the voltage is, (its slightly difficult to probe the circuit but I'm hoping one of these days I can)

The Vout is going to a an external digital input card which is is 30V limited and is also current limited. It's a closed schematic, but they have block diagrams, and from what I can tell, if the digital input voltage is greater than ~0.7 (diode drop), it feeds 3.5mA to an optocoupler for level conversion.

The output from the digital input card seems to oscillate ( switches between 1 and 0) when a voltage is applied to Vin (unknown what the voltage is at the moment).

If we assume that the Vin > 5V constant, wouldn't that mean that Vout is the same as Vin or does the inductor and resistor interfere with the Vout ? I'm not entire sure what the that branch is suppose to do.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN0RUy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

TL;DR: Can the following circuit oscillate if there is a constant voltage on the input ?

Comment: There is no way the circuit you posted an oscillate by itself.

Comment: That's what I was inclined to believe as well before posting. I still have to verify that Vin is not switching at some frequency but I don't think it is.

Comment: You mention that the output from the digital card oscillates - what has that got to do with the circuit above - these are purely passive components on the input to the digital card.

Comment: Because the only schematic I have access too, is what is above. I do not have the schematic from the Vin or Vout. I'm only the middle man. The digital input card is inverted, so an input to the digital in card is HIGH, it's output is LOW. This because of the optocoupler that level shifts. When the card reads a HIGH, it should remain LOW, but instead, it oscillates between HIGH and LOW. Since the cct above is right before the digital in, that's why i posted it in case it could be the cause.

Comment: Do you have a scope image?

Comment: Please use @username so people get notified when you answer their comment.

Comment: @jippie, I don't yet. The PCB is being used right now, and I can't tap into it just yet. I'm hoping to get on it within the next few days when the current users are done with their thing.

Comment: At least you learned the @-trick for now ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I connected the scope and looked at the waveform, there was no oscillation. The problem was that whoever was viewing the data, mixed up the label/pin names and thought that the oscillation was occurring on the circuit above.

As mentioned by some people here, the circuit itself cannot oscillate.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I have to wait 21hours :(

Answer (score 4):

The circuit by itself will not oscillate under constant input.  However if the ground is shared with the digital circuit then you may be getting feedback through coupling to ground.  I'd try isolating the digital ground or adding some decoupling capacitors.

Sparkfun has some good tips on how to isolate ground planes:
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/mixed_signal_design.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot isolate digital and analogs grounds. The PCB is already made, populated and being used for its purpose. Next design I can seperate ground planes, but no such luck right now.

Comment: Have you measured the oscillation with an oscilloscope? Does it occur at the ground plane?  You can try decoupling capacitors - they should be easy to solder between power and ground.